# The eigenvalues obtained from $\,\,y''+\lambda y=0$ with $y(\pi/2)=0,y(0)=-3y'(0)$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am stuck on the following problem:

> Show that the eigenvalues obtained from $$\,\,y''+\lambda y=0$$  with $\,\,y(\pi/2)=0,y(0)=-3y'(0)\,\,$ may be given by $$\lambda_n=4n^2\pi^2\,\, ,(n=1,2,3,....).$$

**What I got from my calculation is :** $A \sin (\frac {\pi}{2}\sqrt \lambda)+B \cos (\frac {\pi}{2}\sqrt \lambda)=0\,\, \text{and}\,\, B=-3\sqrt \lambda A\,\,$ and hence I have deduced that $\tan^2 (\frac {\pi}{2}\sqrt \lambda)=9 \lambda$.

Now,I am stuck and do not know how to do the rest. Can someone help?

EDIT:  $B=-3\sqrt \pi A$ has been replaced by  $B=-3\sqrt \lambda A$.

Comment: @learner, your calculation is correct, but there is an error in the problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three possibilities :

1. $\lambda < 0$ in which case the solution of $A_1e^{\sqrt\lambda t} + A_2e^{-\sqrt\lambda t}$. In this case using the initial condition you can find the arbitrary constants and the eigenvalue.
2. $\lambda = 0$ yields the solution to be $A_1t + A_2$. Similarly, using initial condition you can easily find the arbitrary constants but you know that $\lambda = 0$.
3. $\lambda > 0$ is the one you're interested in. You're calculations are right (just a typo at $B = -3\sqrt\lambda A$).

Then indeed you have $$\tan(\frac \pi 2 \sqrt\lambda) = 3\sqrt\lambda$$
You want solutions of the form $\lambda = (2n\pi)^2$ so simply substitute it and you will see that the equation becomes $\tan(n\pi^2) = 6n\pi$, which isn't true for general $n\in \mathbb N$.

Your problem is incorrect.

Comment: "Ill-posed" is a technical term:  see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ill-posed
In this case the problem statement is just **incorrect**.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for correcting me.